# Basic terraform code for "Platform Configuration" in AzureAD?

Tags: terraform, azure-ad-b2c, terraform-provider-azure

Here is a snippet of the GUI. I want Mobile/Desktop platform for the application but I dont see any terraform documentation related to the same.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With the module `azuread_application` you can manage an application registration within Azure Active Directory.

Specifically with the block `web`:
[image: block web]

More info: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/resources/application